# Angular 8 - Import different libs for different environments

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have 3 different environments: dev, tst and prod for my angular 8 application. I need to import a third party lib based on the environment.

I have 3 different versions - one for each environment. Lets call them

```
lib.dev.js
lib.tst.js
lib.prod.ts
```

Normally, I would import these libs like I would do with `jquery` like this:

```
import lib from 'assets/lib.<environment>.js';
```

How could I achieve this?

**Ps. here's how I serve my application: `ng serve -c=dev`**

angular.json configurations (if matters):

```
...
"dev": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ]
        },
        "tst": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.tst.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
...
```

**Edit:**

Still an issue, though I changed it a bit. Now I import from `index.html`, just like this:

```
<script src="assets/lib.js"></script>
```

Any idea of conditionally importing from template, based on environment?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a workaround for your problem.

In main.ts,

```
    import { browserDynamicPlatform } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { wrappedAppModule } from './app.module';

    export function main(yourEnvironment: string) {
      browserDynamicPlatform().bootstrapModule(wrappedAppModule (yourEnvironment));
    }
```

You can wrap your ngModule like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ProdLib }  from 'assets/lib.prod.js';
import { TstLib }   from 'assets/lib.tst.js';
import { DevLib }   from 'assets/lib.Dev.js';

export function wrappedAppModule (yourEnvironment) {
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
        (yourEnvironment == 'prod') ? ProdLib,
        (yourEnvironment == 'tst') ? TstLib,
        (yourEnvironment == 'dev') ? DevLib
    ]
  })
  class AppModule { }

  return AppModule;
}
```